# выделение памяти для структуры

Tags: c, память, struct, malloc, realloc

Неправильно выделяется память для структуры, нужно ввести структуру данных о книгах, после чего вывести все или по запросу. Как правильно использовать `malloc` и `realloc`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct book
{
    char name[50];
    char authors[50];
    int YearOfPublishing;
    int price;
    int tiraj;
};

int addBook(int size, struct book *t)
{
    if (size > 1)
    {
        t = (struct book*)realloc(t, size * sizeof(struct book));
    }
    printf("Input book name: ");
    scanf("%s", &t[size - 1].name);
    printf("Input authors of book:(...,...): ");
    scanf("%s", &t[size - 1].authors);
    printf("Input year of publishing: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].YearOfPublishing);
    printf("Input price of a book: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].price);
    printf("Input circulation of a book: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].tiraj);
    printf("Book added!\n");
    size++;
    return size;
}

void printBook(int size, struct book *t, int all)
{
    if (all)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            printf("\n%s ", t[i].name);
            printf(" %s ", t[i].authors);
            printf("| %d year ", t[i].YearOfPublishing);
            printf("| Cost:%d ", t[i].price);
            printf("| Circulation:%d\n", t[i].tiraj);

        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Input minimum circulation size:");
        int mincirc;
        scanf("%d", &mincirc);
        printf("Input maximum price:");
        int maxprice;
        scanf("%d", &maxprice);
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            if (t[i].tiraj > mincirc && t[i].price < maxprice)
            {
                printf("<%s> ", t[i].name);
                printf(" %s ", t[i].authors);
                printf("| %d year ", t[i].YearOfPublishing);
                printf("| Cost:%d ", t[i].price);
                printf("| Circulation:%d\n\n\n", t[i].tiraj);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int size = 1;
    struct book *t = (struct book*)malloc(size * sizeof(struct book));
    int menu = 100;
    while (menu)
    {
        printf("Select action:\n");
        printf("1.Add book\n");
        printf("2.Print all\n");
        printf("3.Search\n");
        printf("0.Exit\n");
        printf("_________________________\n");
        printf("You have chosen action: ");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1: size = addBook(size, t); break;
        case 2: printBook(size, t, 1); break;
        case 3: printBook(size, t, 0); break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы «перевыделяете» память в `addBook` (realloc), таким образом модифицируя указатель `t`, но в `main` остаётся «старое» значение указателя. Чтобы это исправить, можно, например, передавать в `addBook` указатель на указатель: `struct book **t`.

Comment: у меня с указателями очень плохо,а с указателями на указатель вообще не работал. Куда я должен поставить указатель?

Comment: @pocketgulag код изменил,при вводе названия в 2 слова перескакивает через поля для заполнения                                     
 `You have chosen action: 1                                                              
 Input book name: fight club                                                              
 Input authors of book:(...,...): Input year of publishing:`

Comment: Это особенность `scanf`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! все работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы «перевыделяете» память в `addBook` (`realloc`), таким образом модифицируя указатель `t`, но в `main` остаётся «старое» значение указателя. Чтобы это исправить, можно, например, передавать в `addBook` указатель на указатель.

Например, может быть такая функция `addBook`:

```
int addBook(int size, struct book **t_pointer)
{
    struct book *t;
    if (size > 1)
    {
        *t_pointer = (struct book*)realloc(*t_pointer, size * sizeof(struct book));
    }
    t = *t_pointer;
    printf("Input book name: ");
    scanf("%s", &t[size - 1].name);
    printf("Input authors of book:(...,...): ");
    scanf("%s", &t[size - 1].authors);
    printf("Input year of publishing: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].YearOfPublishing);
    printf("Input price of a book: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].price);
    printf("Input circulation of a book: ");
    scanf("%d", &t[size - 1].tiraj);
    printf("Book added!\n");
    size++;
    return size;
}
```

И соответственно `size = addBook(size, &t);`

**Обновление**

Если пользователь может ввести такой объём данных, который не поместится в память (скорее всего это не так), то необходима дополнительная проверка.

```
    if (size > 1)
    {
        struct book *t_pointer_new = realloc(*t_pointer, size * sizeof(struct book));
        if(t_pointer_new == NULL){
            return size;
        }  
        *t_pointer = t_pointer_new;
    }
```

**Обновление 2**:

> при вводе названия в 2 слова перескакивает через поля для заполнения

Это неудивительно, ведь `scanf` считывает данные из stdin пока не «увидит» пробел (в том числе).

Можно использовать [fgets](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fgets&category=3&russian=0) вместо `scanf`, эта функция считывает данные до перевода строки. Но здесь есть две особенности: нужно убрать перевод строки и, возможно, пробелы, оставшиеся после `scanf("%d", &menu);` (иначе `fgets` получит только их) и убрать перевод строки, который может попасть в строку с названием.

Вот, что нужно добавить в итоге:

```
#include <string.h>
/*там же где все директивы #include*/
...
    /*вместо scanf("%s", &t[size - 1].name);*/
    int ch = 0;
    do{
        ch = getchar();
    } while(ch != '\n');
    fgets(t[size - 1].name, sizeof(t[size - 1].name), stdin);
    t[size - 1].name[strcspn(t[size - 1].name, "\n")] = 0;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение,но проблему это не решило,при вводе названия книги программа опять начинает работать не корректно,как и без указателя на указатель

Comment: @nikita Странно, у меня всё работает нормально. Может быть, приведёте текущий полный код (обновив вопрос) и что конкретно нужно сделать, чтобы была ошибка?

Comment: `x = realloc(x, ...` это ошибка. Так делать не надо.

Comment: @0andriy в учебных заданиях по крайней мере можно. Едва ли здесь вводится так много данных.

Comment: Если в учебных, тем более нельзя! Потом же будет тяп-ляп и в production.